# Stripped screw in door knob

Tags: doors, screws

I have a stripped screw in my door handle. I tried drilling it to hopefully get a better grip but ended up messing it up further. I believe that i have drilled deep enough to the point where the shank is exposed. [image]

Are there any other ways to remove the screw? Thank you

Comment: Given that we can still see parts of the Phillips screwdriver slot, you are not to the shank yet.

Comment: wd40 is useful for difficult screws because it lowers the torque, which is often limited.

Answer (score 6):

That does not look like you have got down to the shank yet.

Gently keep drilling and the head should come off.

Then if you remove the trim and other parts you should be able to get pliers or grips onto the bit left sticking out and remove it.

Comment: Go find a left-hand drill bit and use a reversing drill to drill with it, and you might just get lucky while drilling and have it unscrew.